# VBA - Apply same MouseMove code to all Labels (Event Handling Collections)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a few Labels on my worksheet, and each one has the following code to display on the Status Bar the Range they're currently at (as the mouse moves over them):

```
Private Sub Label1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

rng = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Label1").TopLeftCell.Address
Application.StatusBar = rng

End Sub
```

Is there any way I can apply this same code to ALL the labels instead of rewriting it over and over again?

Comment: Sorry I don't have the time to write you a good example, but I wanted to point you in a possible direction. Use a collection of "event Handlers". You can add event handler for each label in a loop

Comment: I found a few examples on how to do that, but all of them were for Labels within an userform, so I couldn't completely follow

Comment: Hmm. If your shape has a `mousemove` event I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: I got it to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a new class called LabelHandler:

```
Option Explicit

    Public WithEvents lbl As msforms.Label

Private Sub lbl_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    Dim rng As String
    rng = ActiveSheet.Shapes(lbl.Name).TopLeftCell.Address
    Application.StatusBar = rng
End Sub
```

In a New Module I added the following:

```
Public myLabels As Collection 'Of LabelHandler

    Sub init()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim myLabel As LabelHandler
        Set myLabels = New Collection
       For Each l In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
            Set myLabel = New LabelHandler
            Set myLabel.lbl = l.Object
            myLabels.Add myLabel
       Next
    End Sub
```

Now when I run my cursor over the label, I get $F$11 in the status window

**EDIT**
You will want to edit your For Each loop to only add the label objects you want to the collection. Perhaps by their `Name` property

```
   For Each l In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
        If Left(l.Name,5)="Label" Then
             Set myLabel = New LabelHandler
             Set myLabel.lbl = l.Object
             myLabels.Add myLabel
        End If
   Next
```

Or for all Labels:

```
   For Each l In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
        If l.progID = "Forms.Label.1" Then
             Set myLabel = New LabelHandler
             Set myLabel.lbl = l.Object
             myLabels.Add myLabel
        End If
   Next
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! I'll have to research about the collections now. Any tips of where I can get started?

Comment: Thanks. Class Modules can make programming so much more robust.